# Python 2.7 variable with special char (notation) assign it a to dict changes encoding type

Tags: python, dictionary, character-encoding, decode

I have a notation (ū) in a variable, when I use that variable it displays the notation everywhere. However at a point am assigning that variable to a dict and while assigning the notation is encoded into some other charset automatically (xc5x8d) and  I tried to find which type it is encoding and how to use the same notation inside the dict. I cannot find a solution, am stuck with this problem form yesterday. Thanks for the help in advance. My version of python is 2.7.

Comment: `\xc5\x8d` is a `ō` character, not `ū`. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Why would you use this char in your var name instead of spelling out whatever `ū` stands for? This would have the benefit that the code is more readable and you don't get nasty encoding problems.

Comment: No I have to create question with notations chosen randomly appended to question, am not using it in variable name, but assigning it to a variable.